# Typescript dynamically creating types from object literal

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Sorry this could well be a duplicate as I see lots of similar questions just haven't yet managed to apply those examples to my situation...

Given I call my function `loadStuff()` like so:

```
loadStuff({
  dataExample1: loadDataExample1Fn(),
  dataExample2: loadDataExample2Fn(),
});
```

Where:

- There could be 1 to many dynamic keys to data load calls
- The example `loadDataExample1Fn` has signature `() => LoadedData<DataExample1>`
- The example `loadDataExample2Fn` has signature `() => LoadedData<DataExample2>`

I want the return type to be:

```
LoadedData<{ dataExample1: DataExample1, dataExample2: DataExample2 }>
```

Edit: Added [Typescript playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9gQwCYSQEQcBAeAKgPigF4oBvAKCiqiUwQC4pcBuS6gSwGd5lVGAjOHAA2EBADtW1KFwCiAJ3lx5fKIJFjJ5AL7lyoSFAxZZADwQBbMKICMxMmyoRzV2wElxAMziMJIVrr64NDGCGaW1hAATPYU0s4RolEe3r7i-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)

Anyone able to point me in the right direction in getting typescript support on the returned result?

Comment: Can you create a typescript playground that includes all the related types?

Comment: Sure, added above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed! To do this you'll need to make your function [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), and then generate a return type from the inferred generic type using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)

```
const loadStuff = <L extends { [x: string]: LoadedData<any> }>(
  loadedDataItems: L
): LoadedData<{
  [k in keyof L]: L[k] extends LoadedData<infer D> ? D : never;
}> => {
  // Stuff
};
```

Comment: Great - thanks very much. I don't pretend to completely follow this but will do some reading. 